# How to Calculate the Quantum Cost of Qiskit Circuit

Tags: python, quantum-computing, qiskit

I want to calculate the Quantum cost of this qiskit circuit, e.g as i know x-gate has the cost 1 and there are 4 x-gate so quantum cost for x-gate will be 4. What about ccx gate? How can i calculate its cost.?

```
    circuit.x(qr[1])
    circuit.x(qr[0])
    circuit.ccx(qr[0], qr[1], qr[2])
    circuit.x(qr[1])
    circuit.x(qr[0])
    circuit.ccx(qr[0], qr[1], qr[3])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quantum cost of a Toffoli gate is assessed by taking into account the count of fundamental quantum gates it incorporates, which includes CNOT gates, controlled-V gates, and controlled-V+ gates. Specifically, the case of a Toffoli gate, encompasses two CNOT gates, two controlled-V gates, and one controlled-V+ gate. Consequently, the quantum cost and delay of a Toffoli gate are both measured at 5Δ. [1](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/1877745.1877748), [2](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10773-018-3886-0)

It is to be noted that the cost and delay is 1Δ for all fundamental gates like CNOT gate, Controlled V- gate, and Controlled V+ gate [1](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/1877745.1877748), [2](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10773-018-3886-0).

[1]https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/1877745.1877748.

[2]https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10773-018-3886-0